# The following StackOverflowError was thrown building *widget*(dirty):

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});


  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: DiamondWidget(2),
        ),
    );
     
  }
}

class DiamondWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  DiamondWidget(int counter, /*Image logo */);
  
  int get counter => this.counter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Text('$counter', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)), // Widget 1
          //Image(image: ) // Widget 2
        ]
      );
    
  }
}
```

This puts me this error :

The following StackOverflowError was thrown building DiamondWidget(dirty):
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
DiamondWidget
main.dart:39
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  DiamondWidget(int counter);
  int get counter => this.counter;
```

isn't going anywhere, It is recursive on your snippet.   You can do

```dart
  const DiamondWidget(this.counter);
  final int counter;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
But can you explain me what my previous code was doing please ?

Comment: `DiamondWidget(int counter)` is used to get a value , but you didn't create a variable to that will hold that passed value.  Meanwhile, `int get counter => this.counter;` is referencing itself and create a loophole.